# Is butternut squash with veins OK to eat?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, vegetables

I had two butternut squash sitting on counter for 2 months. One is the usual bright orange inside but the other had white veins. I think it is the low humidity in Arizona allowing the starch to seep out of the flesh. This happens to a lot of my longer kept produce like cantaloupe. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it but my first guess would be mold, especially with the cantaloupe.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but figured if you come across this again.
Squash generally last about one month after they are harvested. If the inner flesh contains any dark or mushy spots, discard it immediately.
I have had some white veins in my squash but they were just harvested and it tasted just fine.  Being that they are at 2 months old I would not risk it.